# Inverting UIImage , reseting alpha caused bad access crash

Tags: ios, uiimage, exc-bad-access

I am trying to invert and image and I need to reset the alpha count too, however it gives a bad access error when I try to do just that (crash at last line). What can't I access the data array? This method works on previous iOS versions.

```
CGImageRef img;
img =image.CGImage;

CFDataRef dataref=CopyImagePixels(img);
UInt8 *data=(UInt8 *)CFDataGetBytePtr(dataref);
int length=CFDataGetLength(dataref);


for(int index=0;index<length;index+=4){


    int alphaCount = data[index+0];
    int redCount = data[index+1];
    int greenCount = data[index+2];
    int blueCount = data[index+3];
    int average = (int)roundf(0.2*redCount + 0.71*greenCount+ 0.07*blueCount);


    alphaCount = average;
    if (alphaCount < 0) alphaCount = 0; 
    if (alphaCount>255) alphaCount =255;
    data[index+0] = (Byte) alphaCount;    <-----WHERE IT GIVES EXEC BAD ACCESS

 ....}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the dataref needs to be set as mutable in iOS6

```
CFMutableDataRef m_DataRef = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(0, 0, CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage)));
```